# How to efficiently determine which nodes can leave a graph while maintaining connectedness?

Tags: graph, time-complexity, graph-theory, connected-components

Suppose I have a graph with node weights, for example:

[image: A graph]

If a node has weight -1, it is "happy". If a node has positive weight, it is "unhappy", and wants to leave the graph.

How do I efficiently calculate which nodes I should kick out of the graph in order to minimize unhappiness (i.e., total graph weight), while making sure that the graph remains connected?

For instance, in this case, I can't get rid of the 10, 8, and 10 nodes, since that would disconnect the graph. The optimal solution in this case seems to be 10 + 8 + 5 = 23.

Comment: The nodes that you cannot remove are called bridge nodes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)  That article incudes a couplie of algorithms for finding the bridge nodes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find bridges (community connecting nodes) in large networks represented using the adjacency matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475116/how-to-find-bridges-community-connecting-nodes-in-large-networks-represented-u)

Comment: Well, the answer to that question recommends finding "communities", and then looking at the bridges. How does that apply here?

Comment: You want to remove nodes that are not bridges.  If you find the bridge node you can avoid removing them.

Comment: Ok, but by the definition of a bridge, the graph in the question has no bridges.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction : the optimal solution in your example is 2 + 10 + 8 + 5 = 25. Nothing prevents you from removing all but connecting "unhappy" nodes.

On the discussion about bridge : bridge are edges, here you remove nodes. This makes a big difference : when removing edges, the nodes remains, and thus you cannot remove too many of them. When removing nodes, their attached edges are removed too, and you can be much more aggressive. So much that you only need to keep path between clusters of "happy" nodes. Everything else is removed.

How do you do that ?

1. Replace each cluster of happy nodes (happy nodes that are connected) by one happy node. (keep track of the replaced nodes)
2. For each edge between an happy and an unhappy node in the starting graph, make an edge between the node representing the cluster of the happy node, and the same unhappy node. The weight is the same as the original weight.
3. For each pair of happy nodes (representing the original clusters), find the shortest path between them. If this path pass through a third happy node, ignore it. Else, make an edge between the two happy nodes, with a weight equal to the total weight of the shortest path. (keep track of the nodes making the path)
4. Remove every unhappy node
5. Find the MST ([minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)) of the graph. Only keep the selected edges.
6. Replace each remaining edge of your graph by the path it represents
7. Replace each happy node by the cluster of happy nodes it represents

I tried to keep this solution in a high language, I can edit it to be more rigorous if needed.